# getting input of characters with getchar() and printing out its reverse with putchar()

Tags: c

I just learned array in C and am trying to make a program that reads a sequence of characters from stdin and stores it in an array, sorts the sequence in reverse order and prints out on stdout.
Intended result example:

Please enter a string. Hello

The number of entered characters = 5

Reversed string is : olleH

Q1

In my program there is no prompt that asks user asking how many characters he is going to input and I am not planning to add one. It just counts the number of characters as it stores them in an array. But the array that I'm using in my program is not a variable-length array. Is it possible to receive different number of characters each time and print them out in reverse order? 
 I'm not sure how putchar() prints out on stdout when it meets null value. I mean, if I initialize a fixed-length array with null value,(such as string[10]={0};), sort its elements' in reverse order and then print them out with putchar(), the first character the putchar function meets (string[0]) would be '\0'. Then does putchar just skip that element? not printing out whitespace? I want to know this because I do not intend to use variable-length array in the program.

Q2

Another question is that when I receive user's input from stdin with getchar, what should be the condition of for loop? I'm planning to manually change the last element of the array as '\0' since in the book it says the last element stored with getchar would be '\n'. But if I write the condition as (ch = getchar()) !=  '\n' then would '\n' not be stored in the array?? should I write the condition as (ch = getchar()) != EOF? But can I use EOF here even if I am not reading from a file using fopen function??

Q3

In the code that I wrote, errors occur with 'bufferSize' variable that I defined. I can't see what causes the problem.

Thank you

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# define bufferSize 50

int i;
int getString (char string[], int bufferSize);
void printString ( char string[], int sizeString);
void reverseString ( char string[], int sizeString);

int main (void){

    char string[];
    int sizeString = 0;
    int bufferSize;

    sizeString = getString(string, bufferSize);
    reverseString(string, sizeString);
    printString(string, sizeString);

    return 0;
}

int getString (char string[], int bufferSize){

    printf("Please enter a string. ");
    for( i = 0; i < bufferSize && (string[i] = getchar())!=EOF; i++){
        sizeString++;
    }

    string[sizeString]='\0';

    printf("The number of entered characters = %d\n", sizeString); 

    return sizeString;
}

void reverseString ( char string[], int sizeString){
    int j = sizeString - 1;
    i = 0;
    int temp;

    while (i < j) {
        temp = string[i];
        string[i] = string[j];
        string[j] = temp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }

    return;
}

void printString(char string[], int sizeString) {
    printf("Reversed string is: ");
    for (i = 0; i < sizeString; i++) {
        putchar(string[i]);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: `char string[];` isn't valid. `bufferSize` is uninitilized variable. And This replace with `50` by macro.

Comment: `#define bufferSize 50` does the same thing as if you would use "find and replace" in your editor to replace `bufferSize` with `50` everywhere in your code. So the precompiler changes `int bufferSize;` to `int 50;` which does not compile.